# Proving a string is random

Tags: computability, kolmogorov-complexity

I am reading Kolmogorov Complexity by Li and Vitányi:

"Let $x$ be a finite binary string. We write '$x$ is random' if the shortest binary description of $x$ with respect to the optimal specification method $D_0$ has length at least $x$."
By length $x$ I understand the natural number that the binary string maps to canonically.

[proof which I do not understand follows]

"This shows that although most strings are random, it is impossible to effectively prove them random."

However, I am able to produce a counterexample and can find a proof that $x$ is random effectively (there is an algorithm). Iterate over all the words of size up to $x-1$ of a description language. If you find a description $\alpha_x$ such that $D_0(\alpha_x)=x$ ($\alpha_x$ describes $x$) then terminate with verdict that $x$ is not random. If you exhaust all the words of length $<x$(there are finitely many since $x$ is finite so the program halts) and none of them describes $x$ and then terminate with result that $x$ is random.

What is wrong in my counterexample?

Comment: how do you verify that $D(a) = x$ in finite time?

Comment: If it was not finite, then the output would be indeterminate but $D$ maps every description to some object.

Comment: It is by a definition of a description mapping.

Comment: You could just read further into Li and Vitanyi's book for the details, but maybe this will help: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Algorithmic_complexity#Prefix_Turing_machine

Answer (score 2):

The catch is that $D_0$ is only a *partial* recursive function and it may not be possible to verify that $D_0(\alpha) = x$ in finite time. There is no way around that because $D_0$ must be universal, and there is no way a machine implementing it would halt on every input, because not every Turing machine halts on every input.

Comment: Isn't iterating over all strings of length $|x|-1$ also *not* effective?

Comment: @MarkG There is only a finite number of them, so that's not a problem. It's not efficient, but that's not a requirement.